# What is the correct way to use source_address

Tags: python, sockets

I have come across a corner in `socket` in **Python3.5**. When running the code below something is wrong and an error is thrown.

```
import socket

print(socket.create_connection(('www.baidu.com', 80), source_address=('127.0.0.1', 8998)))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                     
    File "demo.py", line 4, in <module>                                                                  
    print(socket.create_connection(('www.baidu.com', 80), source_address=('127.0.0.1', 8998)))         
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 707, in create_connection                            
   raise err                                                                                          
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 698, in create_connection                           
   sock.connect(sa)                                                                                  
   OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is **don't**!

You can't play with low level Python sockets not knowing how BSD TCP stack is working and how to use BSD sockets.

The `source_address` is - as it clearly states - source address and port for you connection. You MUST NOT make connection from loopback interface address to the address in the *outside world*.

So, the `invalid argument` error is correct.

Do you really need to set `source_address`? Why don't let that to the operating system?

Comment: That's it. I have forget the '127.0.0.1' is a local ip address. However, in thus situation if i do not know this, how can we debug it?

Comment: I don't think you can. This is low-level socket implementation and you have to know what you're doing. You would have exactly the same problem trying to use the `connect()` function in C language. However you have some smart souls on stackoverflow, where you can ask :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the source address `127.0.0.1`. The server can't reach you on this address, its just locally on your computer. This is your local loopback address. You have to use your public IP address.

So best is let the system set the source address like the other answer says.

```
 socket.create_connection(('www.baidu.com', 80))
```

Comment: Yes, just as @Michał F said, I have realized this lately. :)